# Separar clientes em foreach com mpdf

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, mpdf

meu cenário é o seguinte, gero um arquivo pdf utilizando a biblioteca mpdf e esse arquivo pdf é uma consulta de intervalos entre código do cliente e data de evento. Ex.: codigo: 0001 ate 0004 e 0000-00-00 ate 0000-00-00. Está gerando o pdf com o resultado perfeitamente, porém preciso separar as informações de cada cliente, porque elas estão sendo exibidas juntas, veja a imagem  e segue o código onde gero o pdf:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o código esta aqui https://pastebin.com/DQrWjv3K

Obrigado desde já

Answer (score 0):

O relatório está certo. Penso que se deve apenas colocar o loop de produtos `foreach($reports as $r)` dentro do de clientes `foreach($clients as $c)`, e após este loop de produtos realizar um espaçamento ou quebra de página com `$mpdf->AddPage();`, assim separando cada cliente com seus produtos.

Comment: obrigado, funcionou dessa maneira de utilizar o foreach dentro do outro.

Comment: @ThiagoMoreira, marque a resposta para não deixar a pergunta em aberto.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido da seguinte forma:

https://pastebin.com/r9MXGxSu

Obrigado @C.Bohok